# Manupilating Process Output in Win Forms (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, process, backgroundworker

I have a WinForms application that runs multiple processes which run as background workers. I create a background worker for each new Process

```
BackgroundWorker background = new BackgroundWorker();
background.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bkWorker_DoWork);
background.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bkWorker_Complete);
background.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
background.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

My Dowork code looks like this:

```
private void bkWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
  WorkerArgument obj = (WorkerArgument) e.Argument;
  BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker) sender;

  Process proc = new Process();
  proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmdprocess"; //"cmd.exe";
  proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
  proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
  proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
  proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

  proc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);

  proc.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(ErrorOutputHandler);

  proc.Start();

  process.Add(obj.Row, proc.Id);
  proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
  proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
  proc.WaitForExit();
  proc.Close();
}
```

As you may notice that I am using an event handler to sort the output given by the cmdProcess (SortOutputHandler) same as Error output.

I am showing this output in a text box

```
 private void SortOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine) {
   if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data)) {
     if (txtLog.InvokeRequired) {
       this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
         string[] lines = txtLog.Lines;
         if (lines.Length > 200) {
           string[] newlines = lines.Skip(200) as string[];
           txtLog.Lines = newlines;
         }
         txtLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
       });
     } else {
       string[] lines = txtLog.Lines;
       if (lines.Length > 200) {
         string[] newlines = lines.Skip(200) as string[];
         txtLog.Lines = newlines;
       }
       txtLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
     }


   }
 }
```

The Error Handler is as follows:

```
private void ErrorOutputHandler(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data)) {
    if (txtLog.InvokeRequired) {
      this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
        string[] lines = txtLog.Lines;
        if (lines.Length > 200) {
          string[] newlines = lines.Skip(200) as string[];
          txtLog.Lines = newlines;
        }
        txtLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);

      });
    } else {
      string[] lines = txtLog.Lines;
      if (lines.Length > 200) {
        string[] newlines = lines.Skip(200) as string[];
        txtLog.Lines = newlines;
      }
      txtLog.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + outLine.Data);
    }

  }
}
```

The problem is that when the number of processes increases the log starts running rapidly.

I have created a new Form frmLog with a multi-line textbox inside it, Can you tell me How I can use it to get Output from one process? Like there can be a "View Log" Button and when I click it only the log of that process show.

Also is it possible to write the output of all the processes to unique files separately?

Comment: so, instead of using your textbox, you would prefer to save the files to a dedicated log file per process? This you could do relatively easy by evaluating the sendingProcess, and writing only to the file that is associated with the sender process. Why is it my impression that this question is a continuation of previous questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, consider please as an example following type to hold process output

```
interface IProcessOutput
{
  IReadOnlyCollection<string> Cerr { get; }
  IReadOnlyCollection<string> Cout { get; }
  void OnError(string text);
  void OnOutput(string text);
}
```

Then, starting a new process, instantiate a type that implements this interface and "bind" events to corresponding objects.
I encourage you use Queue (as IReadOnlyCollection) if you want to roll your logs (with 2000 or whatever limit) because Queue holds head and tail internally so it does not allocate/move memory if you keep capacity of some limit. It is fast enough for it.

Change GUI so that ListBox with log output can belong to any of running processes (kind of master/detail). So, once you select a process, you will see corresponding log lines.

Instead of textbox, please use ListBox. Use BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() while loading strings into it. If your output is huge, use self-drawing in listbox so you do not need to store strings into its' Items collection rather access queue objects directly.

PS: Be ready to receive strings that form not a complete line (without new line char). The event with output is internally called when process flushes file handle (cerr, cout are also file handles). So if process flushes it in the middle of a string - you will get half of the string.